# Emphasizing multiple keywords in a string with regex and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of objects with string properties that I search through with multiple keywords using regex. For example if the collection looks like this

```
collection = [
    {searchString: 'Troarn Lower Normandy France'},
    {searchString: 'Tröbitz Brandenburg Germany'},
    {searchString: 'Tröbnitz Thuringia Germany'},
    {searchString: 'Tröchtelborn Thuringia Germany'},
    {searchString: 'Trochtelfingen Baden-Württemberg Germany'},
    {searchString: 'Trockenborn-Wolfersdorf Thuringia Germany'},
    {searchString: 'Trodena Trentino-Alto Adige Italy'},
    {searchString: 'Trodica The Marches Italy'},
    {searchString: 'Trofaiach Styria Austria'},
    {searchString: 'Trofarello Piedmont Italy'}
];
```

and I have a text string to search with like this

```
text = 'tro france';
```

I get the keywords by splitting the text

```
keywords = text.split(' ');
```

and then build a regex from those keywords

```
regex = '';
for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++ ) {
    if (keywords[i] !== "" && keywords[i] !== undefined) {
        regex += "(?=(^|.*\\s)" + keywords[i] + ")";
    }
}
regex = new RegExp(regex, "i");
```

so the text `'tro france'` would give this regex `/(?=(^|.*\s)tro)(?=(^|.*\s)france)/i`
and would match the first item in the collection.
I would search through the collection like this

```
for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i].searchString.search(regex) !== -1) {

        // ... do stuff here

    }
}
```

But now I would like to emphasize the keywords in the search string.
For example if the text was 'tro france' I would like the words 'tro'
and 'france' to be underlined where I display the result. I can do this
in a simple way but I'm not sure how to do multiple matches and
replacements. I have one already but it only works as long as I don't do
a space and jump to other keywords.

For example if the text is simple and "non jumping" but straight forward match like `'Troarn Lo'` then I can replace it like this

```
emphasized = new RegExp('('+text+'.*?)', 'i');
emphasized = collection[i]searchString.replace(emphasized, '<em>$1</em>');
```

But I'm completely blank on the multiple keywords part.

So again if text is `'Tro Lo Nor Fra'`, I could match the first item in the collection with the regex, but after that, I want to underline those keywords kind of like I did above, except for all of the keywords.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer depends on which browser you have/want to support. All new browsers support it, however it *may* give you problems in old IEs (I found no exact compat infos for it).

Instead of clumsy regexes, you can also use the `String.prototype.indexOf`. <strike>It has the disadvantage, that it does *not* have the guaranteed order of the initial string</strike>*, however it has the following advantages:

- it does not use slow regexes
- it returns you the index, where the actual search string appears, giving you the oportunity to insert your markup at exactly those positions
- it is able to return "partial" hits (e.g. "these results matched two of your three searchterms"):

your modified example:

```
keywords = text.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
        var position = collection[i].indexOf(keywords[j]);
        if (position !== -1) {
           /* keyword[j] has been found at [position], so you could do: */

           // insert "<em>" markup into string at [position]
           // increase the matchcounter by 1
        }
    }
}
// show results according to matchcounter, e.g. full match only
// (matchcounter === keywords.length)
```

edit: * actually, you can use the second parameter position to start the search from the position of your last hit.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm going to try this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: One question. Is the indexOf method much faster than the regex match? Do you know how much faster it is on a hunch? Just curious about performance in general.

Comment: @gottfried well, as it turns out, the result is not unanimous, as it's faster in some browser and in others it isn't: http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof Anyway, I prefer simpler methods and also generally avoid `new` wherever I can, as it leads to confusing effects (e.g. strings). But I guess you are free to go with either method, depending on what you need.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm going to try that method anyways to learn different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You might combine all of the keywords into a single regular expression. Note that this will make the g-flag mandatory.

```
emphasized = new RegExp(keywords.join('|'), 'ig');
emphasized = collection[i].searchString.replace(emphasized, '<em>$&</em>');
```

Note that this will highlight *every* occurrence of every keyword. Also, use `<mark>` instead of `<em>`. And the keywords should be escaped when used with RegExp.

Comment: doesn't this search for the exact `text`, which is basically useless since there may be other symbols in between the words other than a single white space?

Comment: @Christoph oh, right, I forgot the vertical bar as argument to join.

Comment: when I try this it gets replaced by the string '$0' and not the keyword itself.

Comment: 'no' gives $0rway, instead of <mark>No</mark>rway, for Norway

Comment: @gottfried oh, I'm sorry. It seems that one uses $& instead of $0 for the entire match in ES. I adjusted the answer (again).

Comment: Did you, by any chance. rage downvote my answer? Nevermind, I vote your answer up anyway, since I really like it.

Comment: @Christoph I don't even have that privilege yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I will do that:

```
var query = 'tro  al it';

// first we extract the terms from the query and we normalize them:
var corr = {
    'ae':'(?:ae|æ)', 'oe':'(?:oe|œ)',
    'ss':'(?:ss|ß)', 'ß':'(?:ß|ss)',
    'a':'[aàâä]', 'e':'[eéèêë]', 'i':'[iîï]', 'o':'[oôö]', 'u':'[uûü]',
    'c':'[cç]', 'y':'[yÿ]' }; // need to be completed

var terms = query.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(?=[aeiyoucs])(?:[ao]e?|[eiuçy]|ss)/g, function (m) {
        return corr[m];
     }).split(/\s+/);

// now we build patterns to be able to filter or to find:
var testPatterns = terms.map(function (item) {
   return new RegExp('(?:^|[- \'])' + item, 'i');
});
var HLPattern = new RegExp('(^|[- \'])(' + terms.join('|') + ')', 'ig');

// usage:
var results = collection;

// to filter the results:
testPatterns.forEach(function(pattern) { 
    results = results.filter(function (item) {
        return pattern.test(item.searchString);
    });
});

// to highlight the results:
results = results.map(function (item) {
    item.searchString = item.searchString.replace(HLPattern, '$1<em>$2</em>');
    return item;
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was interesting, I will look in to it. I didn't even think about foreign characters like that. Thanks man!